# Place text along a path

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, nodes, paths

I'm using the decorations library to put text along a path. But the text does not appear on the path, instead, it appears in the node, how should I correct it? Also, the dotted path is not symmetrical, is there a way to make it clean and look symmetrical? How do I make solid lines of equal length?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.multipart,chains}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex'] 
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
minimum height=2em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
% Place nodes
\node [block] (init) {model};
\node [cloud, left of=init] (expert) {$\mathbf{\Lambda}$ };
\node [cloud, right of=init] (system) {Predict};

\path [line,dashed] ([yshift=3ex]{init}) to[out=-90,in=-90,looseness=2.2]  ([yshift=-.5ex]{expert}) node [midway, above, sloped] (TextNode) {path text};

\path [line] (init) -- (system);
\path [line] (expert) -- (init);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several changes.

- You should use `\tikzset` instead of `\tikzstyle`. See the code below for the syntax.
- Use `anchor=` to measure spacing from the edge of the node instead of the center.
- Use the `decorations.text` library.
- To get the text path symmetrical, draw it to the same height as the bottom of the rectangle and then extend it to the circle.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.geometric, arrows, decorations.text}
\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, 
        text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
    cloud/.style={draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm, minimum height=2em},
    line/.style={draw, -latex'}
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
% Place nodes
\node [block] (init) {model};
\node [cloud, left of=init, anchor=east] (expert) {$\mathbf{\Lambda}$ };
\node [cloud, right of=init, anchor=west] (system) {Predict};

\path [line] (init) -- (system);
\path [line] (expert) -- (init);
\draw [line, dashed] 
    [postaction={decoration={text along path, reverse path, text align=center, text={path text}}, decorate}]
     (init) to[out=-90, in=-90, looseness=2.2] ([yshift=-2em]expert) to (expert);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to place "path text" in a straight line along the path instead of curving around?

Comment: Yes. It's actually much easier: `\draw [line, dashed] (init) to[out=-90, in=-90, looseness=2.2]node{path text} ([yshift=-2em]expert) to (expert);`. Then you don't need `decorations.text`. "Text along a path" usually means curved along the path. You just want to label the path with a node.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear, what you looking for. I guess, that for something like this:

[image]

i.e. that text is on the first straight solid arrow and not on dashed curve.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}%{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes, shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
node distance = 22mm, 
  start chain = going right,
   arr/.style = {-Stealth},
  base/.style = {draw, semithick, minimum size=2.2em, font=\sffamily}, 
 block/.style = {base, text width=5em, align=center, rounded corners, fill=blue!20}, 
 cloud/.style = {base, ellipse, fill=red!20}
                    ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain, join=by arr}]
\node [cloud] (expert)  {$\mathbf{\Lambda}$};
\node [block] (init)    {model};
\node [cloud] (system)  {Predict};
    \end{scope}
\path   (expert) to ["path text"]    (init);
\draw[arr, dashed] (init) to [out=240, in=300] (expert); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For labels above arrow is used `\quotes` library, for dashed line for edge option `bend left=60`. Exploited is `chains` library, which is loaded in document preamble. Nodes styles are defined as options in `tikzpicture`. By this are removed obsolete `\tikzstyle` definitions used in your MWE.